# Can I limit Github issue creation of a public project to members?

Tags: github

We have an open-source project in a public Github repository, and we want to use issues for qualified bug tracking and other things. However, we don't want to allow everyone to create issues, but only project members.

Is this somehow possible with Github? In Gitlab, there's a setting for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not to be possible at the moment. I have created this:

https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/7421